# Implementing "group flush" in server-side Netty handler

Tags: netty

I have a server implemented in Netty which is working well but now I'm trying to optimize one aspect.

The incoming channels are multiplexed i.e. each client process has many threads sending requests and reading responses over a single connection to the server.

The server handler channelRead() receives each request in turn, and dispatches it to a thread pool for execution. The execution will cause responses to be written to the channel.

Currently, each response is flushed immediately using ctx.writeAndFlush(). I am looking for a design pattern in Netty where I can optimize so that if multiple threads are writing messages to the same channel at the same time, I can have multiple messages batched together in a single flush (i.e. a group flush) to reduce the number of syscalls.

I'd appreciate any pointers in implementing this Netty-style.

Thanks,

Andy.

Answer (score 1):

Just use ctx.write(...) and once you have written enough call ctx.flush(). This will try to do a gather write with everything written so far. So just one syscall.

Comment: it seems ctx.flush still send msg one by one? so why one syscall？

Comment: ctx.write:  add mgs to buffer. ctx.flush() send msgs oneby one

Comment: i check the code again, it merge msgs to one syscall, so you are write,